# How to Pass a Const from a File to Another

Tags: javascript, variables, vue.js, constants

I'm having trouble passing the following `const clouds` from one file to another.

*I'm totally missing something here and I've been staring at this too long - Your help is greatly appreciated!*

**From: getAVWXData.js**

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export function getAVWXData() {

  axios.get(
    https://some_url
  )
  .then((response) => {
    const v      = this     
    const res    = response.data
    const clouds = res['Cloud-List'][0.0][1];
    console.log('Give me Clouds! ' + clouds) // <-- This works
  })
}
```

**To:**

```js
import { getAVWXData } from './get-avwx-data'

getAVWXData()
console.log('Give me Clouds! ' + getAVWXData.clouds) // < Returns undefined!
```

Comment: `getAVWXData()` is an asynchronous function. You're checking a split second after it's called, before it completes and runs its `.then` condition.

Comment: I figured that was what was going on. However, I was stuck on figuring how to prevent that using `.then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return a promise with a value:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function getAVWXData() {

  return axios.get(
    https://some_url
  )
  .then((response) => {
    const v      = this     
    const res    = response.data
    return res['Cloud-List'][0.0][1];
  })
}
```

and:

```
import { getAVWXData } from './get-avwx-data'

getAVWXData().then((result) => {
  console.log('Give me Clouds! ' + result.result) // <- Should Return a value
})
```

Comment: Thnx! I was having trouble with using return correctly earlier and figured that was the reason.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `getAVWXData` does not return any data, and also the data you are trying to retrieve is within a resolved promise. In order to get the `clouds` value, you will need to do something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function getAVWXData() {

  return axios.get(
    https://some_url
  );
}
```

and

```
import { getAVWXData } from './get-avwx-data'

getAVWXData().then((response) => {
  console.log('Give me Clouds! ' + response.data.clouds)
});
```

You must wait until the promise is resolved to get the data from the response.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. This would work too but I accepted the answer above because it helps separate logic and junk from the importing file. (I should have stated this in my question).